# Как сделать один jmp_buf для нескольких файлов?

Tags: c, try-catch

я пытаюсь сделать свой блок try-catch-finally на С. Для этого я решил использовать старую, позабытую, но еще рабочую стратегию SJLJ (setjmp-longjmp). Все работает вполне хорошо, но только для одного файла. Как только я пытаюсь выбросить исключение (а именно указатель на структуру, хранящие данные об исключении), то `jmp_buf`, который я вызываю экстерном, и который находится в общем подключаемом файле, по какой-то причине остается недоступным.

Теперь описание:

*Exception.h*

```
static volatile _declspec(thread) jmp_buf env = { 0 };  // сюда идет буфер прыжка
static _declspec(thread) volatile struct Exception *__e = NULL; // а это указатель на эксепшн, который идет с ним
```

*main.c*

```
#include "Demo.h"
#include <stdio.h>


main()
{   
    if (!setjmp(env)) // по сути try
    {
        struct Demo *GD = newdemo();
        GD->method();   
    }
    else //catch
    {
        printf("good");
    }
}
```

*Demo.h*

```
#pragma once
#include "Exception.h"

struct Demo
{
    void(*method)();
};

struct Demo* newdemo(); //прототип функции
```

*Demo.c*

```
#include "Demo.h"
#include <malloc.h>

void method() // oт сюда хочу возвращать
{
    longjmp(env, 1); //!! здесь выкидывает ошибку, что env пуст 
}

struct Demo* newdemo() // выделение памяти и подвязка функции
{
    struct Demo* dp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Demo));
    dp->method = method;
    return dp;
}
```

пример сильно упрощен, но ошибка та же что и на большом проекте. Как сделть буфер одним на все файлы?

Если есть идеи о том, как еще можно сделать трай кетч, тоже было бы неплохо.

Comment: Для фанатов велосипедостроения https://exceptions4c.guillermo.in :)

Comment: https://github.com/guillermocalvo/exceptions4c В папке Lite есть лёгкая версия: только из одного заголовочного файла и одного файла исходников.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так вы же объявили свой буфер как `static`! В результате каждая единица трансляции получает свой независимый буфер. Тот буфер, на котором вы делаете `longjmp` не имеет никакого отношения, к тому буферу, на котором вы делали `setjmp`. Разумеется, ничего не работает.

О том, как правильно объявлять глобальные переменные в С тут уже писали сотни раз. В заголовочном файле вы делаете *объявление*

```
extern volatile jmp_buf env;
```

а в одном из файлов реализации - *определение*

```
volatile jmp_buf env = { 0 };
```

(Я убрал ваш `_declspec(thread)`, чтобы не захламлять код лишними деталями. И я не знаю точно, как в этом контексте cработает `_declspec(thread)`).

Это относится ко всем *глобальным* переменным, которые вам нужны.

P.S. `volatile` на `jmp_buf` не нужно.

P.P.S. `int main(void)`, а не `main()`.

Comment: в ином случае пишет, что символ уже определен

Comment: @Ilya Pakhmutov: Ну так! Разумеется, пишет! О том, как правильно объявлять глобальные переменные в С тут уже писали 100500 раз.

Comment: какая разница, что дает этот воид в скобках

Comment: @Ilya Pakhmutov: Разница в том, что объявления функций с пустыми `()` уже давно официально являются *deprecated* в языке С. То есть они подлежат удалению из языка. Это не ошибка (пока), но выглядит как небрежность. Вы ведь не используете K&R объявления в функций в других контекстах? Почему вдруг здесь?

Comment: а есть объяснение, чем же они так насолили?

Comment: Тем, что такое объявление является частным случаем старинного синтаксиса K&R объявления функции. Оно не задает количества и типов параметров функции. Язык С уже давно перешел на объявления с *прототипами*, т.е. с указанием количества и типов параметров функции. K&R объявления тем временем удаляются из языка и сидят в нем лишь для обратной совместимости с кодом времен динозавров.

Comment: судя по § 6.7.6.3(14) в стандарте языка С11, эти конструкции эквивалентны, а K&R объявления я использую, потому, что я учился по учебнику Кернигана и Ритчи, пока профессора не могли объяснить ни как языки работают, ни как нужно правильно. Собственно по этому я пытаюсь сделать что-то подобное С++ сейчас, я изучаю таким образом его

Comment: @Ilya Pakhmutov: Вы неправильно проинтерпретировали это параграф. Вот ответ комитета по стандартизации на этот же вопрос: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_317.htm. Пустые скобки `()` с точки зрения грамматики являются `identifier-list`, но не являются `parameter-type-list`. А объявления функций с `identifier-list` никогда не являются прототипами. Обратите внимание: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8ff222b1d51b8b0

Comment: понял, благодарю за объяснение

Comment: "...а K&R объявления я использую..."? Вы действительно в своем коде пишете объявления в стиле `void foo(a, b, c) int a; double b; char c; { ... }`? Именно так должно выглядеть K&R объявление для функции с параметрами.

Comment: в случае с винапишными так и делаю, там параметров много и они длинные, удобно в столбик писать, хотя в последнее время уже не использую почти, ибо от макроса бывает трудно отличить. По сути я сейчас пишу что-то наподобие С с классами, поэтому придерживаюсь плюсовой нотации